# How to use Regular-Expressions find repeated characters in string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have got a task

> "Turn character that is single into '(' and character that are
>   repeated into ')'
>
> for Example "TAAreTheBest" into ")))())()()()"

From above the character that have turn to ')' is T,A,E.

> So key is I want to use REGEX to find out which characters is repeated and replace it with ')'

These are code that I have try it before and it doesn't work for me

```
(\w)\1* 
([a-zA-Z])\1*
\w{2,}
```

I am very new to python. And I want to learn more about REGEX so I think this task could use regex to solve it. So please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is not supposed to be done from one `sub`

```
import re

string = 'baTAAreTheBestaaaaabbbbaaaaaaa'

#1 replace chars that occur more then twice
tmp = ''
while tmp != string:
  tmp = string
  string = re.sub(r'(\w)(((.*)\1){2,})', r')\2', tmp)

#2 replace consecutive pairs (dunno why this are not handled by 3rd replace)
string = re.sub(r'(\w)\1', r'))', string)
#3 replace separate pairs
string = re.sub(r'(\w)(.*)\1', r')\2)', string)
#3 replace unique chars
string = re.sub(r'\w', '(', string)
print(string)
```